# How to add commas to axis label numbers for numbers with 5or more numerals in R?

Tags: r

I am using `labels = comma` from the `scales` package to give commas, however it gives commas for numbers with 4 numerals ie `5,000` instead of `5000`. How can I specify commas for numbers 5 numerals or above.

What I currently have:

```
scale_y_continuous(labels = comma, breaks=c(5000, 10000, 15000, 20000, 30000, 40000, 50000))
```

Desired output:

axis labels `5000 10,000 15,000 20,000 30,000 40,000 50,000`

Comment: you might find `prettyNum` helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround you can create a custom function which scales the numbers based on their length:

```
# load packages
library(ggplot2)

# define dummy data
rand_data <- data.frame(
  x = 1:100,
  y = sample.int(n=50000, size=100)
)

# define function for custom comma
custom_comma <- function(x) {
  ifelse(nchar(as.character(x)) >= 5, scales::comma(x), x)
}

# plot dummy plot (old)
ggplot(rand_data, aes(x=x, y=y))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma, breaks=c(5000, 10000, 15000, 20000, 30000, 40000, 50000))

# plot dummy plot (solution)
ggplot(rand_data, aes(x=x, y=y))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = custom_comma, breaks=c(5000, 10000, 15000, 20000, 30000, 40000, 50000))
```

Old scales:

[image: Old Plot]

New scales (based on function):

[image: new plot]